# Do web images scale automatically?

Tags: android, webp

In my Android project, if I use [WebP](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/WebP) images, should I still support each screen density, as if I had PNG images and JPEG images, or do WebP images scale automatically like SVG images?

Comment: Have you learnt the answer?